How can I make a NET MAUI Windows App install alongside Windows Services?
I am unfamiliar with creating installers and I'm trying to make a Windows desktop application that uses Windows services in the background, I would like to make a simple installer where it installs the application itself and the services in the same installation process. How should I go about this?
I have looked into the Wix toolset but there are not many internet resources for NET MAUI. There also aren't many resources for installing services with MSIX.

You can refer to these docs: Create a Windows Service installer | Bundle MSIX packages.
